# PHP for function get POSTED values

Tags: php

I have this PHP/HTML Code:

```
<form method="post" action="create_quote2.php">
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Select</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Image</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Sale Price</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?php
$sql="SELECT * from products ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$counter=0;
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $counter++;
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="product'.$counter.'" value="'.$_POST["checkbox$i"].'" />';
    echo '<tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="'.$result["sequence"].'" name="checkbox'.$counter.'" /></td>
                <td>Image</td>
                <td>'.$result["title"].'</td>
                <td>&pound;'.$result["saleprice"].'</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" size="20" /></td>
              </tr>';
}
echo '<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="'.$counter.'" />';
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

so when boxes are checked you go to the next page with this code:

```
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Image</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Sale Price</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Trade Price</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Total Cost</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=$_POST["counter"]; $i++)
{
    if($_POST["checkbox$i"])
    {
        $counter++;
        $sql="SELECT * from products where sequence = '".$i."' ";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);     
        echo '<tr>
                    <td>Image</td>
                    <td>'.$result["title"].'</td>
                    <td>&pound;'.$result["saleprice"].'</td>
                    <td>&pound;'.$result["tradeprice"].'</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>';   
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

it works fine and selects all the correct products from the products table but i need a way to get the posted quantity values for each row.

how can i display the posted quantity values on the second page?

P.S. im not worried about SQL injection on this code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<input type="text" name="qty'.$counter.'" id="qty'.$counter.'" size="20" />` on the first page

Then `$_POST["qty{$counter}"]` or `$_POST['qty'.$i]` in the relevant cell

As a side note, you may find it easier to use a HEREDOC structure so that you don't have to keep on adding quote marks to echo stuff:

```
echo <<<BLOCK
<tr>
    <td>Image</td>
    <td>{$result["title"]}</td>
    <td>&pound;{$result["saleprice"]}</td>
    <td>&pound;{$result["tradeprice"]}</td>
    <td>Quantity - {$_POST['qty'.$i]}</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

BLOCK;
```

I found HEREDOC a great help as the quote marks don't blend into one another so much

Comment: perfect - apart from its only doing one line. if i check 2 boxes and put in quantities i only get a posted quantity of the first line etc but the title of the results shows on the other lines

Comment: I see where i went wrong. I think I should have used `$i` rather than `$counter`. Edited my answer. Hopefully it's right. As an aside, what is `$counter` used for? It's not referenced in the block

Comment: $counter was there from previously. i have removed it now -  thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

To get your quantities just change:

```
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" size="20" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="qty'.$counter.'" id="qty" size="20" />
```

and then reference the same way you do for other inputs.